# Android - Keep the app work in background

Tags: android

I want to know how to keep the app working and responding to its functions even when I enter another app. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it like *background* tasks or you actually want to send *commands* to it?

If is background tasks, you want to use a Service: [Android Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: I meant that, when I launch the app and then hit the Back button or just switch to another app, my app will still respond to all of its features.

Comment: Oh so you want your app to be able to respond to all of its features when you return to your app?

Comment: No. I want my app to respond to any of its features in any other app I enter.

Comment: How do you plan on connecting to your background app if it is in the background?

Comment: I don't really know, that's why I came here.
Do you know how to make a background notification?

Comment: It depends what your app does. What functions will it perform?

Comment: Basically, the functions supposed to work while I enter other app.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach that with [Services | Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)